# Valor de variable no cambia al usar SetTimeout en React.js

Tags: reactjs

```js
let color = "red";

function Application(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      color = "yellow",
      console.log(color)
    }, 5000)
    
    console.log(color)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <p>Is a tag</p>
    <span id="span" className={color}></span> 
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```css
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Hola, estoy aprendiendo React y me he topado con un problema al usar `setTimeout`, el nuevo valor de la variable no se aplica a la clase despues de 5 seg, ¿Porqué sucede eso?, he comprobado usando un console y si cambia el valor en la consola pero la clase sigue estando en red y no en yellow.

Creo que en React usan un obj llamado `state` para cambiar el estado de un componente, si es por eso, como puedo hacer para que después de 5s cambie de red a yellow, Gracias!

Comment: Lo que mencionas del `state` es cierto. El [ciclo de vida](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) de un componente de react es el encargado de re-renderizar los elementos del DOM que lo necesitan, por lo tanto, si quieres que react renderice un objeto luego de que exista un cambio debes de hacerlo por medio de las técnicas que especifican en la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).

Comment: @FranAcuna encontré una solución usando una clase y no una funcion, dentro de la clase, cree un objeto llamado this.state, y luego a ese objeto le asigne una propiedad color, despues llame a un metodo llamado componentDidMount() donde dentro tiene un setTimeout y funciono. Aca dejo un video que soluciono el problema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t8sAYah1C4

Comment: Sí, todo eso está en la documentación de React, puedes crear elementos por medio de clases (utilizando los métodos del ciclo de vida de React como `componentDidMount()` ) o puedes utilizar elementos funcionales con `hooks` como `useEffect`. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación, no hay nada que reemplace leer la documentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar `state` no puedes decir color = "red". Solo puedes cambiar el valor con `setState("nuevo valor")`. Y cuando escribes `setTimeout(() =>...`como aquí el codigo va a correr cada 5 segundos. Entonces necesitas usar `useEffect` con un `[]` como el segundo argumento para que solo se ejecute una vez.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setColor("yellow");
      console.log(color);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>Is a tag</p>
        <span id="span" className={color}>
          Hola
        </span>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Voy a probar tu código, recién estoy empezando en React y hay cosas nuevas por aprender :)

Comment: Puedes leer más sobre los setState useState y useEffect hooks [aquí](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) ;)

Comment: Funciona bien!, aunque me confundio un poco la manera de hacer las cosas en React, igual tengo que leer la documentación, gracias!